# Merging two list of objects but removing duplicate on the basis of id field

Tags: java, arrays, oop, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists of object customer. One list represents customer with subscription to XYZ and another subscription to ABC package. I want to combine both the lists but if there is any customer with same id in both list I want to update a flag that it subscribes to both packages. E.g. flag is 1 if package is XYZ, 2 if ABC and 3 if both. How can I do this using java streams? 
I tried using the below but it just give me list of the one common.

```
List<FindCustomer> filteredList = xyzPackage.stream()
          .filter(sh -> abcPackage.stream()
            .anyMatch(sp -> 
              sh.getId().equals(sp.getId())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to group the subscriptions by id. When a duplication is found then "merge" the result by updating the subscription flag. Last step is to return the `Map#values()` as list:

```
List<FindCustomer> concatenatedSubscriptions = Stream.concat(subscriptionABC.stream(), subscriptionXYZ.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(FindCustomer::getId, Function.identity(), (c1, c2) -> {
      if (c1.getFlag() != c2.getFlag) {
        c1.setFlag(3);
      }
      return c1;
    }), map ->  new ArrayList<>(map.values())));
```

Comment: This works for me. Thankyou so much. Just a question to understand this logically, how is this IF CHECK working here?

Comment: If c1 and c2 differs (i.e. [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1], [1, 3]) then the flag is set to 3 else it will remain.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the clarification.